# j_scurity_check blocks other servlets

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets, jaas

I'm trying to impose jaas code onto a working web app, let's call it iBook, using Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 8.

The Webcontent folder contains an index.html, and the jaas login.html and error.html (though I call the error page signup.html).

The resource I'm trying to place under jaas control is the editor folder, a.k.a. /iBook/editor.

When I go to my app's index.html, I get redirected to the jaas login.html, which contains the form that points to j_security_check, which does work---if I enter bogus credentials, I get refused service, with a "no credentials" exception sent to the console.

But the login.html page also contains some other forms, to allow 1) on-the-spot user account creation, 2) handling of forgotten passwords, and 3) changing password. Each of these forms points to the servlet ManageUserAccounts. by which I want to, well, manage user accounts.

The security-constraint element in web.inf looks like this:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>IBook Editor</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/editor/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/signup.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```

When i comment the security-constraint out, the manage-accounts servlet works. When the constraint is in place, manage accounts does not work.

I have a break point in the doPost() method that I cannot reach when the security constraint is active, but I can reach it simply by commenting out the constraint (and redeploying the web app to Tomcat).

Can anybody help? Point me in the right direction? Slap me down for a dumb mistake (while, of course, politely describing the mistake and offering a possible course of remedial action)?

Thanks.

Jerry

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with jaas, but in spring security you need to create a wildcard url-pattern and set its access to some role: `<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />`. In your case you could try to use something like spring's `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`. What do you actually mean by "manage accounts does not work" what kind of error do you get there?

Comment: No error, it just doesn't do anything.  The ManageUserAccounts servlet is referenced in the location bar, but the web page is always the j_security_check login page, no matter what URL I try to use to escape.

Comment: what HTTP-Code do you get for the POST request? Open Developer-Tools in your browser and go to network-page. Check what requests your browser doing and what response do you get from the server

Comment: http 200.  As far as the server is concerned, everything is fine.  Except that the page that is displayed is the login.html page, even though the location bar points to the ManageUserAccounts servlet. And, as noted by the breakpoint that never gets hit when I run the application in the Eclipse debugger, the servlet is never hit.